# How to receive message from Twilio via websockets?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, nestjs, twilio

I need to recieve audio data from calls in progress from Twilio via WebSockets.
I am using Nest.js + socket.io.
Here is the code:

```
public async startCall() {
    const wsUrl: string = 'wss://2ed5-176-115-102-89.ngrok-free.app';
    const call: CallInstance = await this.client.calls.create({
      from: '+...',
      to: '+...',
      method: 'GET',
      twiml: `<Response>
<Start><Stream name="my_first_stream" url="${wsUrl}"/></Start>
<Say>What's up!</Say>
<Pause length="60" />
<Stop><Stream name="my_first_stream" /></Stop>
</Response>`,
      record: true,
    });
  }
```

websocket.gateway

```
@WebSocketGateway()
export class WebsocketGateway
  implements OnGatewayInit, OnGatewayConnection, OnGatewayDisconnect
{
  @WebSocketServer()
  private readonly server: Server;
  private readonly logger: Logger = new Logger(WebsocketGateway.name);

  afterInit() {
    this.logger.log('Websockets initialized');
  }

  @SubscribeMessage('media')
  handleEvent(@MessageBody() data: any): string {
    console.log(`New event "media"`, data);
    return data;
  }

  handleConnection(client: Socket): void {
    console.log(client);
    this.logger.log(`Client id:${client.id} connected`);
  }

  handleDisconnect(client: Socket) {
    console.log(client);
    this.logger.log(`Client id:${client.id} disconnected`);
  }
}
```

I see in ngrok terminal that I receive some requests and that my websockets gateway successfully initialized, but I don't see any logs about connections and call is creating and I can response to it via my phone.

What am I doing wrong?

**I FUCKED THESE WEBSOCKETS, I AM THE WINNER, WORKS GOOD WITH WS INSTEAD OF SOCKET.io**